# how to change or replace logo (.svg) file in CorelDRAW X8

Tags: coreldraw

can anyone please help me to change logo in CorelDRAW X8 i am trying to change in .SVG file but no luck will you guys please give me tutorial or something please

Answer (score 0):

If you import the SVG in Corel, select it and 'degroup', you may adjust it as you do with other drawings. Then export as SVG and that's it.